# jQuery: Get all links from HTML page except if the link falls under certain class or id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div>
  <a href="#">Link4</a>
</div>
<div>
  <p>
    <a href="#">Link5</a>
  </p>
</div>
<p>
  <a href="#">Link6</a>
</p>
<div class="stackoverflow">
  <a href="#">Link7</a>
  <a href="#">Link8</a>
  <a href="#">Link9</a>
</div>
<p class="stackoverflow">
  <a href="#">Link10</a>
</p>
<p>
  <a href="#">Link10</a>
</p>
```

What is the best way to ignore all the links under class stackoverflow and select all the rest of anchor tags in the dom?

Is selecting every anchor tag `$('a')` and then grabbing `$('.stackoverflow a')` anchor tags and then removing the common elements the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `:not()` pseudo class like this:

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/u0opybcg/)

```
$('a:not(.stackoverflow a)');
```

This will negate all `a` elements that are descendants of a `.stackoverflow` element.

Alternatively, the `.not()` method would work as well:

```
$('a').not('.stackoverflow a');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `filter` function :

```
$('a').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).parent().hasClass('stackoverflow');
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('a').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).parent().hasClass('stackoverflow');
}).css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link1</a>
    <li>
      <li><a href="#">Link2</a>
        <li>
          <li><a href="#">Link2</a>
            <li>
</ul>
<div>
  <a href="#">Link4</a>
</div>
<div>
  <p>
    <a href="#">Link5</a>
  </p>
</div>
<p>
  <a href="#">Link6</a>
</p>
<div class="stackoverflow">
  <a href="#">Link7</a>
  <a href="#">Link8</a>
  <a href="#">Link9</a>
</div>
<p class="stackoverflow">
  <a href="#">Link10</a>
</p>
<p>
  <a href="#">Link10</a>
</p>
```